# separate database for SSIS logging

Tags: sql, sql-server

I read it somewhere"

> "A separate database should be created
>   if SSIS logging is required. (Do not
>   use the Sysdtslog90 table in either
>   master or msdb. This is not a security
>   related concern but could be a
>   performance issue since SSIS can
>   generate a lot of logging data.
>   Microsoft recommends creating a
>   separate database for logging."

Why? Just to keep things separate and be more organized or there is a deeper meaning to this?

Regards

Manjot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a performance issue since SSIS can
>   generate a lot of logging data

To be able to finely control the I/O path of the logging data: on which LUN, how many spindles etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's generating a lot of log information, it may compete with the other database functions if they are sharing the same physical disks.  This means both your logging and your database could take a performance hit.